# Iterate a Nested Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My dictionary is structured as such:

```
stockData = {
    'AAPL': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300}, 
    'GOOG': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300}
     }
```

and here is area where i assign values:

```
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # Each row in the spreadsheet has data for one census tract.
    company_name  = sheet['A' + str(row)].value
    ticker = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    sector = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    shares = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    price = sheet['E' + str(row)].value
    total = sheet['F' + str(row)].value
    beta = sheet['G' + str(row)].value
    dividend = sheet['H' + str(row)].value
    number_stocks+=1

    # Make sure the key for this ticker exists.
    stockData.setdefault(ticker,{})
    stockData[ticker]['company_name'] = company_name
    stockData[ticker]['sector'] = sector
    stockData[ticker]['shares'] = shares
    stockData[ticker]['price'] = price
    stockData[ticker]['total'] = total
    stockData[ticker]['dividend'] = dividend
    stockData[ticker]['beta'] = beta
```

I'm having an issue where i am iterating using a for loop over the dictionary to add a new value 'percentage' which is the 'total' divided by the sum of all the totals of all stocks.

```
def get_portfolio_value(stocks,item):
    portValue = 0
    percentage = 0
    for k, v in stocks.items():
        portValue = portValue + v.get(item,0)
        stockData[ticker]['percentage'] = stockData[ticker]['total']/portValue
    print(portValue)

get_portfolio_value(stockData,'total')
```

the issue is that the get_portfolio_value function is getting me the entire portValue total of the portfolio, but the line where i am trying to add the percentage of the portfolio to each stock isn't working righ--it is only oddly enough appearing for only one of the stocks.  Can someone advise?

Comment: following @jDo, where does `ticker` come from?

Comment: @jDo sorry i didn't include the top code where i am reading from an excel file and assign values.  That single quote was just an error in me typing the code in here. i just edited my post to include value assignments.

Comment: is there a good way to also sum the stock percentages by 'sector'?  for example to get a list of all of the sectors with the total percentage for that sector...for all of the stocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly, you may try as follows (I just copied the `stockData` below):

```
stockData = {
    'AAPL': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 'total': 300},
    'GOOG': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 'total': 300}}
```

I guess this is what you meant:

```
def get_portfolio_value(stocks, item='total'):
     portValue = 0
     for v in stocks.values():
        portValue += v[item]
     for k in stocks.keys():
        stocks[k].update({'percentage': stocks[k]['total'] / portValue})
    print(portValue)

get_portfolio_value(stockData, 'total')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
stock_data = {
    'AAPL': {'beta': 1.01833975315094, 'company_name': 'Apple', 'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 'total':300},
    'GOOG': {'beta': 1.01833975315094, 'company_name': 'Apple', 'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 'total':300}
}

stock_sum = sum(stock_data[item]['total'] for item in stock_data)

for item in stock_data:
    stock_data[item]['percentage'] = int((float(stock_data[item]['total']) / stock_sum) * 100)
```

**Result:**

```
>>> for item in stock_data:
...     print stock_data[item]['percentage']
...
50
50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved in two parts:

1. Take the sum of total stocks. For that you may use [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) as:

   ```
   stock_sum = sum(stock_data['total'] for stock_data in stockData.values())
   ```
2. Iterate over the value to update the entry. Since you do not need `key`, use `dict.values()` to iterate over just the values:

   ```
   for stock_data in stockData.values():
       stock_data['percentage'] = stock_data['total']/stock_sum
       #   ^ Adds new key into your existing `dict` object
   ```

Now the values of your `stockData` dict holds additional key as `percentage`

Comment: This is perfect!  Works like a charm!  Thank you so much, i am still very much a beginner at Python, but I definitely appreciate advice from those much wiser than I.

Comment: No need of thank you. If you find the answer useful, [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It might help someone else facing the same issue in future