# Iterate Dictionary in Python and Sum Totals by Category

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This question is in relation to this post here:

[Iterate a Nested Dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898818/iterate-a-nested-dictionary-in-python/40899629#40899629)

As a follow up, i am trying to sum the totals for all stocks and get the total percentage of a stock in a portfolio by sector.

I want the output to look like this:

Technology: 24%, Financials: 14%, etc etc

My dictionary looks like this:

```
stockData = {
    'AAPL': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300
        'sector': 'Technology}, 
    'GOOG': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300
        'sector':Technology}
     }
```

I have calculate a total percentage of the overall portfolio for each stock like this:

```
for stock_data in stockData.values():
    stock_data['percentage'] = stock_data['total']/stock_sum
```

and i'm trying to get % totals by sector but just not working.... I tried this.

```
for stock_data in stockData.values():
    sector_totals = []
    for stock_data['sector'] in stock_data:
        sector_totals = (stock_data['sector'], stock_data['percentage'])
```

Any advice?

Comment: BTW: the dictionary above is invalid, missing quotes and commas.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your `stockData` creating a `sector` dictionary which collects all the totals for that sector:

```
sectors = {}
for stock in stockData.values():
    sectors.setdefault(stock['sector'], []).append(stock['total'])
print(sectors)
# {'Technology': [300, 300]}
```

Then you can iterate over the `stockData` adding the `percentage`:

```
for stock in stockData.values():
    stock['percentage'] = stock['total']/sum(sectors[stock['sector']])
```

Note: In py2 you will have to make one of these a `float`, e.g. `float(stock['total'])`

Alternatively, you could create a running total for the `sector` dictionary and this would avoid the `sum()` above:

```
sectors = {}
for stock in stockData.values():
    sectors[stock['sector']] = sectors.get(stock['sector'], 0) + stock['total']
print(sectors)
# {'Technology': 600}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason not to use pandas? 
http://pandas.pydata.org/
It will make your life much easier.

I have added an extra (fake) stock to make the example more relevant.

```
stockData = {
    'AAPL': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300,
        'sector': 'Technology'}, 
    'GOOG': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300,
        'sector':'Technology'},
    'XXXX': {
        'beta': 1.01833975315094,
        'company_name': 'Apple',
        'dividend': 1.9341673320912078, 
        'total':300,
        'sector':'Food'}
     }

import pandas as pd

# Create pandas dataframe wi
stockData_df = pd.DataFrame(stockData).T
stockData_df['percentage'] = stockData_df['total']/stockData_df['total'].sum()


stockData_df
Out[82]: 
         beta company_name dividend      sector total percentage
AAPL  1.01834        Apple  1.93417  Technology   300   0.333333
GOOG  1.01834        Apple  1.93417  Technology   300   0.333333
XXXX  1.01834        Apple  1.93417        Food   300   0.333333



sector_totals = stockData_df.groupby('sector').sum()['total']/stockData_df['total'].sum()

sector_totals
Out[86]: 
sector
Food          0.333333
Technology    0.666667
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Comment: this is really helpful.  i might try it this way.  I'm really fairly new to Python and haven't yet explored it yet...but now I think i have a good reason to.  Thank you!