# Outputting Python To Word Document

Tags: python, dictionary, pprint

I've been following along in Automate the Boring Stuff.

This question follows my two previous questions here:

[Iterate a Nested Dictionary in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898818/iterate-a-nested-dictionary-in-python/40899629?noredirect=1#comment69028156_40899629)

[Iterate Dictionary in Python and Sum Totals by Category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901549/iterate-dictionary-in-python-and-sum-totals-by-category?noredirect=1#comment69016880_40901549)

I've been using the methods used in ATBS to print out some data from my python code to a word document.  The following is a snippet of how this is setup:

```js
dataFile = open('stocks.py', 'w')
wordFile = open('stocks.doc', 'w')
dataFile.write('allData = ' + pprint.pformat(stockData))

wordFile.write(pprint.pformat(sectors))
```

My question is two fold.  First, i have a dictionary called 'sectors' that holds a key 'sector' with a 'percentage' value.  I want to output this to a table in word like so:

Technology  30%
Health Care 20%
Financials  30%

but i'm not finding it easy via the pprint method.  Is there a good way to do this?

my second question--is--is there a better way to be doing this?  i know ATBS is sort of the beginners way of using python but i'm open to trying a better way of using python to analyze my data in excel and then generate an automated report in Word.

Comment: The [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module is invaluable for this kind of thing.

Comment: i just tried using that and it didn't seem to be working--my thinking is that it might not be compatible with 3.5.  do you know if that might be the case?

Comment: If it's possible, downgrading your Python from 3.5 to 3.4 could solve your problem.

Comment: The docs say 3.4.